# cannot resolve default_web_client_id in android studio

Tags: android, performance

I'm getting this error on an Android Studio project using the Firebase.

[image]

I'm getting the error as cannot resolve `default_web_client_id`

Comment: Please add a description of the error in the question itself. The image alone doesn't provide a lot of specific detail.

Answer (score 2):

If you have tried everything and didn't get solved. Try to run the app, it will successfully run and your app will work like charm.

I got the same error and still, it's giving me the red line.

But I tried to run the app and It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I know its a very late answer, but it will perfectly work in both, **Windows** and **Mac**.
Just do few things mentioned below:

1. Open your app in [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).

2. Go to **Project Settings** and add your **SHA-1 Fingerprint**.
3. Download **google-services.json** and place where your old **google-services.json** was.
4. Restart Android Studio.
5. Go to Project view and go to `YOUR_APP\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values`
6. Open **values.xml**.
7. There will be a line like this:
   `<string name="default_web_client_id">YOUR_ID</string>`
8. Then copy **YOUR_ID**.

You will get your id instead of **YOUR_ID**

9. Then paste it just above this line:
   `GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOption.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)`.

*Your final Google Sign In Options Code will look like this:*

```
    String default_web_client_id = "YOUR_ID";
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(default_web_client_id)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Well The solution is simple and easy.** Most of the developers finds the error when they closed the project and reopen it then the default_web_client error results.

**Solution**:

You need to add the client id in the

res-->values-->string

**Add this**

`<string name="default_web_client_id" translatable="false">xxxxxxxx</string>`

for the client id(xxxxxxxxx) you can go to Firebase console and paste here.